# Row colors hiding after sort column

Tags: c#, gridview, colors, pageload

I have gridview and in method **page_load** I am painting rows. When I sorting gridview by clicking on name this painting it is hiding and not reloading that colors. 
How can I fix that?

Comment: You could start by showing us the relevant code...

Comment: did u used javascript to coloring this Row??

Comment: @MohammedAlasa'ad No I coloring by 'row.BackColor = Color.Red;'

Comment: @krolik1991 yes your right I checked issue and row coloring crashed on sorting you may show us your code to help u 
Hint: Maybe u called row.BackColor = Color.Red only on page load where you must call it on sorting event too

Comment: @MohammedAlasa'ad I fixed this by add the same coloring on RowDataBound Event

Comment: @krolik1991 Great :)